# need help to float a header in a wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, css-float

i need help with a wordpress theme, i want to localize a theme but i have some problemes my new blog is in arabic (rtl) and i want to replace the theme logo in the right (float to right) and the banner ad to the left side in the header, also i tried to float the search bar to the left but i did not succeed in that, can you please help me to localize this great theme? ah i forget to tell you the theme name is "Vanillia" http://newwpthemes.com/wordpress-theme/vanillia/ here is a screenshot of what i need to do (http://) i47.tinypic.com/28cg0ax.png

Answer (score 0):

for the search part and for the logo in the header part use this class
DRight{float:right;padding-right:20px;}

for the top menu and the advertisement in the header part the styles are
DLeft{float:left;padding-left:20px;}

Padding-left and padding-right - Gives the 20px space from the left side as well as the right side